# Creating an alias that has PWD as variable

Tags: linux, navigation, alias, csh

I would like to create an alias for the following command:

```
cd `pwd | sed 's/\(.*\/main\/lib\).*/\1/'`/h
```

But I can't seem to pass `pwd` as a variable. Instead it takes the directory at which the .alias file is located at. 
I have tried using `$PWD` or `'\$pwd'` and I can't seem to get it to work.

How can I create an alias that for this command?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work for me:

```
 alias H='cd $(pwd | sed "s=\(main/lib\).*=\1=")/h'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried it but it is gibing me an error when I execute the alias.  `Illegal variable name.`

Comment: @bobesfanchi: What shell do you use?

Comment: @bobesfanchi: [Top Ten Reasons not to use the C shell](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt)

Comment: That page clearly says the problem is with csh scripting; not interactive shell usage.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: I prefer to have the interactive and scripting environments similar. YMMV.

Comment: There is something to be said for that, I certainly won't deny csh limits, but it does get somewhat annoying that almost every question about (t)csh has someone stating that you "should not use csh. period" as an absolute with no context, even though it's clearly about interactive shell usage, and even for scripting, there are reasons to use it (legacy/computability)...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: `csh` tag was missing before. I mentioned "should not use" only in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a function instead:

```
hcd() { cd $(sed 's#\(.*/main/lib\).*#\1#' <<< "$PWD")/h; }
```